# Solution of this ODE

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE?
$$i\partial_tv=t^q|v|^pv$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $v$ is complex valued?
I think that separation of variables is to be used.

Answer (score 1):

If $v\ne 0$, then
$$
\frac{\partial_t v}{v\lvert v\rvert^p}=-it^q
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{p}\partial_t\left(|v|^{-p}\right)=i\frac{1}{q+1}\partial_t\big(t^{q+1}\big)
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{p}|v|^{-p}=i\frac{1}{q+1}t^{q+1}+c,
$$
for some $c$ constant.

Note that we have used that $(|x|^k)'=k|x|^{k-2}x$.

Comment: In the third line a $\partial_t$ in the righthand side disappeared; why?

Comment: The second line is the derivative of the third line.